# usage of __DIR__ in a class

Tags: php, dir

I'm writing a very simple PHP application that returns the path of the file with a slight modification.

this is my code:

```
<?php
class abc {

 private $path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'moshe' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

 function doPath() {
 echo $this->path;
 }

}


$a = new abc();
$a->doPath();
```

I get the error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /mnt/storage/home/ufk/1.php on line 4

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /mnt/storage/home/ufk/1.php on line 4
```

for some reason I cannot add connect **__DIR__** using '.' to another string. what am I missing?

using PHP 5.5.13.

Comment: What you want to do is a bad practice called **tight-coupling**. What if you have to change a path later? You'd modify the code!

Comment: so what should I do instead?

Comment: Instead you should pass a path as a parameter like this `public function __construct($path){ $this->path = $path; }` then `new abs(__DIR__ . '/moshe/');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prior to the introduction of [constant scalar expressions in PHP 5.6](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs), you could not define class properties dynamically. This example is now valid on modern PHP versions.

```php
    private $a = 5 + 4;  // evaluated, wont work before PHP 5.6
    private $a = 9;      // works, because static value
```

Your solution:

```php
class abs
{
    private $path;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "moshe" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol interesting, do you have a reference?

Comment: [Constant scalar expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

Answer (score 2):

[You can't calculate properties in their class definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

If you need a variable to be initialized to a default value that can only be determined by an expression, you can do it with a constructor.

```
public function __construct ()
{
    $this -> path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'moshe' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
```

However, the above is a really bad design for various reasons that I won't get into here.  You're far better off passing the path in as an argument, as this will allow you far more flexibility.  For example, if you want to test the class you can have it write to a different location when testing it and not affect live data.

```
public function __construct ($path)
{
    if (!is_dir ($path)) {
        // Throwing an exception here will abort object creation
        throw new InvalidArgumentException ("The given path '$path' is not a valid directory");
    }

    $this -> path = $path;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is the answer, and this answer should be up-voted and accepted. But you're late dude, that's the matter of time.