# Parse error in php5.5 but no error in php5.6

Tags: php, composer-php

I have downloaded facebook ads sdk using composer. The autoload_static.php file is working fine on my system, having php5.6:

```
<?php

// autoload_static.php @generated by Composer

namespace Composer\Autoload;

class ComposerStaticInit8e6cb1db46baaf6145a1d53efc8ef72b
{
    public static $prefixLengthsPsr4 = array (
        'F' => 
        array (
            'FacebookAds\\' => 12,
        ),
    );

    public static $prefixDirsPsr4 = array (
        'FacebookAds\\' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds',
        ),
    );

    public static function getInitializer(ClassLoader $loader)
    {
        return \Closure::bind(function () use ($loader) {
            $loader->prefixLengthsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit8e6cb1db46baaf6145a1d53efc8ef72b::$prefixLengthsPsr4;
            $loader->prefixDirsPsr4 = ComposerStaticInit8e6cb1db46baaf6145a1d53efc8ef72b::$prefixDirsPsr4;

        }, null, ClassLoader::class);
    }
}
```

But, for php5.5, it is showing error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in lib/vendor/facebook-ads-php-sdk/composer/autoload_static.php on line 19
Errors parsing lib/vendor/facebook-ads-php-sdk/composer/autoload_static.php
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Can't see any syntax error in line 19 of that code, sorry.

Comment: Are you using php5.6? It's not showing any error in case of php5.6.

Comment: No, I do not use outdated versions here. I only look at the code. What I meant to express is: are you really sure that this is the correct file and line number? No change here due to copy&paste or the like?

Comment: Yes. I am also surprised with the error.

Comment: Please look into the following question, seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547682/usage-of-dir-in-a-class

Comment: Worse a try, though this is a different situation: It could be that the array definition is invalid using a dynamic component. However I fail to see why this is declared as a "syntax error"...

Comment: PHP 5.6 allows constant expressions. Earlier versions expected a static value.